# Bound the complex roots of a polynomial above

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, complex-numbers, roots

We consider $P(z)=a_{0}+a_{1}z+\cdot+a_{n-1}z^{n-1}+a_{n}z^n$, with $a_{0},\ldots,a_{n-1},a_{n} \in \mathbb{C}$ and $a_{n}\neq0$.
Let $R=\max_{0\leq k\leq n-1}\left | \frac{a_k}{a_n} \right |$ and $S=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left | \frac{a_k}{a_n} \right |$.

Can you help me establish the two following ?

a) Any complex root of $P$ has modulus less than or equal to $\max(1,S)$.

b) Any complex root of $P$ has modulus less than or equal to $1+R$.

It is worth noting that the approximation in b) is often better than that in a).
Thank you for any hint or answer.

Comment: Did you ask 7 questions in the last 12 hours, including 5 in the last 2 hours? You might wish to slowdown a little... By the way, mentioning where you are stuck, what you tried and where you failed is well considered on this site.

Comment: @Didier: The OP asked another one: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98138/the-graph-of-cot-is-the-image-of-the-graph-of-tan-by-a-simple-transformati

Comment: and one more: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98139/inequality-for-with-cot

Comment: @Paul: Indeed. *Sigh*.

Comment: I understand your amazement for so many questions but I'm doing this because I found some interesting problems about complex numbers on the internet (more precisely here : http://www.eleves.ens.fr/home/kortchem/cg/complexes_expbs.pdf). Maybe this is stupid, but I wanted to post the questions before trying to solve them so that I would have the solutions ready when I would be stuck. I hope this does not disturb much. Or does it ?

Comment: And for this problem, the case $\left | z \right |\leq1$ is trivial. Thus we can suppose $\left | z \right |>1$.When $z$ is big, thepreponderant term of $P(z)$ is $a_{n}z^n$ and this can help us get a majorization. For b) I guess we should use geometric series (with ratio $\left | z \right |$ or $\left | \frac{1}{z} \right |$?

Comment: DidierPiau : "By the way, mentioning where you are stuck, what you tried and where you failed is well considered on this site."                              I'll try to act accordingly in the future.

Comment: *I wanted to post the questions before trying to solve them*... This is outrageous, if you ask me.

Comment: @Didier: the beauty of it is that he's trying to sell us [the hints](http://i.stack.imgur.com/tZkrs.png) in [his exercise sheet](http://www.eleves.ens.fr/home/kortchem/cg/complexes_expbs.pdf) as his guesses.

Comment: And is there any issue with that ? Maybe this could have helped someone find the answer. Anyway, next time I'll try to think some time before asking questions. Sorry for that and thank you for the advice.

Comment: And I did not sell them as guesses. Just mentioned them here for you to know.

Comment: *And I did not sell them as guesses*... Obviously, you have a lot to learn about the generally accepted practices of attribution in mathematics. You copy verbatim several sentences from a document without mentioning the source, as if these were your own, and you *do not even see the problem*?! Since you ask, probably rhetorically: *Is there an issue with that?* let me answer: yes there is!

Comment: @t.b. Yes. And now, a propitious change of username... Maybe momo1729 is supposed to cover the tracks of IsmailLemhadri.

Comment: Just pardon me to say that I did mention the source in a previous comment (http://www.eleves.ens.fr/home/kortchem/cg/complexes_expbs.pdf). What I want to insist on is that you should not view my comment as an attempt to show you that I have made guesses about the problem ; this would simply be useless because I openly mentioned that I had not tackled it yet.

Comment: And by the way, the username change certainly does not come with the intention of hiding anything or whatsoever. I guess I should just not publish my real name on the Internet -that's something I should have done from the day I registered, even though M.SE encourages users to do so.

Answer (score 4):

Fix $\delta>0$. To solve the first question, we apply [Rouché's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%27s_theorem) to the circle of center $0$ and radius $\max\{1,S\}+\delta$. Indeed, if $|z|=\max\{1,S\}+\delta$,
$$|P(z)-a_nz^n|=\left|\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}a_jz^j\right|\leqslant \sum_{j=0}^{n-1}|a_j||z|^j<\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}|a_j|(\max\{1,S\}+\delta)^n\leqslant  |a_nz^n|.$$