# Inequality for $\cot$

Tags: trigonometry

How can I prove that for all $t\in[0,\frac{\pi}{2}], \cot^2t\leq\frac{1}{t^2}\leq1+\cot^2t$, with $\cot$ the cotangent function ?
Thank you

Comment: Are you sure you have written the inequality right?

Comment: Pretty much, yes. Why ?

Comment: I think we can derive a simpler inequality to prove from the given inequality, and prove it by derivatives or similar.

Answer (score 1):

Start with $0<\sin x < x < \tan x$, square, and take reciprocals.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8337/different-methods-to-compute-sum-limits-n-1-infty-frac1n2/8353#8353.

Answer (score 0):

This is an elaboration of Hans Lundmark's answer:

Consider the portion of the unit circle in the first quadrant. For an angle $t$ in the first quadrant, consider the triangle $\triangle OIQ$ where $O=(0,0)$, $I=(1,0)$, and $Q=(\cos t, \sin t)$.
Let $Z$ be the point of intersection of the line passing through $O$ and $Q$ with the vertical line passing through $I$.

Then
$$
\text{area}(\triangle OIQ)\le\text{area}( \text{sector}(OIQ))\le\text{area}(\triangle OIZ).
$$

This gives
$$
{1\over2}\sin t\le {t\over 2}\le {1\over2}\tan t;
$$
whence
$$
{1\over \sin t}\ge{1\over  t}\ge {\cos t\over \sin t}.
$$
From this
$$\eqalign{
&\cot t \le{1\over t}\le \csc t\cr
\iff& \cot^2 t\le {1\over t^2}\le \csc^2 t\cr
\iff&\cot^2\le {1\over t^2}\le 1+\cot^2 t, 
}
$$
where we used the Pythagorean identity $1+\cot^2 t=\csc^2 t$ in the last inequality.

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to present a *Calculus approach* to the question, even if I don't know if it can satisfy the OP (because of the restriction imposed by the *Trigonometry* tag).

Let $x=\tan t$, thus the inequality becomes:
$$\frac{1}{x^2} \leq \frac{1}{\arctan^2 x} \leq 1+\frac{1}{x^2} =\frac{x^2+1}{x^2}$$
with $x\in ]0,\infty[$; therefore, taking the reciprocals, it suffices to prove:
$$\frac{x^2}{x^2+1} \leq \arctan^2 x \leq x^2\; .$$
The rightmost inequality is trivial, for we know that $\arctan x\leq x$ when $x\geq 0$, hence we have to work on the leftmost inequality.

Now, taking the squares the inequality to prove becomes:
$$\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} \leq \arctan x \; ,$$
or, equivalently:
$$\tag{1} \arctan x -\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} \geq 0\; .$$
Let, for sake of simplicity, $f(x):=\arctan x-\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$: since $f(0)=0$, we can prove inequality (**1**) by showing that $f$ increases in $[0,\infty[$. In order to do this, we evaluate the derivative of $f$:
$$f^\prime (x) = \frac{1}{1+x^2} -\frac{1}{(1+x^2)\sqrt{1+x^2}}=\frac{\sqrt{1+x^2} -1}{(1+x^2)\sqrt{1+x^2}}$$
and we see at once that $f^\prime (x)\geq 0$ when $x\geq 0$ (because $\sqrt{1+x^2}\geq 1$) thus $f$ increases strictly in $[0,\infty[$ and $f(x)\geq f(0)$, which is (**1**).