# Polynomial $p(z)$ in $\mathbb{C}$ has no zero whose modulus does not exceed $1$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

For $n>1$ consider real numbers $c_0>c_1>.....>c_n>0$.
Prove that the polynomial $$p(z) = c_0+c_1z+.....+c_nz^n$$ in $\mathbb{C}$ has no zero whose modulus does not exceed $1$.

Comment: "...has *no* zero whose modulus *does not* exceed $1$." My brain hurts.

Comment: @AWertheim [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98137/bound-the-complex-roots-of-a-polynomial-above)?

Comment: This is a well known problem. See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188039/showing-that-the-roots-of-a-polynomial-with-descending-positive-coefficients-lie). Apply the transformation $q(z) = p(\frac{1}{z} ) $.

Comment: That's just it, @PeterTamaroff! Thanks. :)